# Eclipse save error when trying to open the design view of a synapse config file in WS02 Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm following the tutorials and samples of the official [WSO2 ESB documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Samples). When I create (or load) a synapse configuration in the WSO2 Developer Studio I'm getting the error as shown below:

> Save problems
>
> Save could not be completed.
>
> Reason:
> resources\sunErrorHandler.esb_diagram (The system cannot find the path specified)

[image: Eclipse Error]

This error shows up when I want to open anything in the Design view. Even when I'm not trying to save anything.

So far I have tried to add the path specified in the error, but without success. I already found a workaround to be able to save and deploy my ESB configurations. By using "Save as" I'm able to keep the changes I made in the XML files. However the error stills shows up when I open the new version of the file.

Does anyone know a better solution to permanently resolve this error message?

Comment: WSO2 DVS version? Do you tried to use a fresh eclipse and import the same project?

Comment: Use a DevStudio version > 3.8.0. You can avoid this error as from 3.8.0 it does not use _diagram files. You can cleanup those files and reimport.

Comment: I used a clean install of eclipse + DevStudio version 3.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well, running eclipse.exe as administrator fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Issue remains unresolved for my Eclipse + DevStudio 3.8.0 install on a Windows 10 environment. However since I was experiencing some other issues with the WSO2 ESB I decided to migrate to a Linux (Ubuntu) environment. This seems to work much better, the eclipse does not seem to have this issue on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse want to write in C:\Program Files\eclipse\resources. I solve problem by adding full permissions to group users on folder C:\Program Files\eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in Mac you can provide the required permission to the "/Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/resources" folder.